# System.UnauthorizedAccessException with Admin Privileges

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, manifest, execution

I'm having some issues with my application, that have to access the "C:\" directory. An unauthorized access exception occurs when I try to do it. I've already tried to change the execution level in app.manifest to:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" />
```

and

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess= "true"/>
```

and

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess= "false"/>
```

The main code of the exception is:

```
List<string> search =
    Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\", "*.exe*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Can anyone help me please? I'll be very thankful!

Comment: This probably isn't your problem, but `@"C:\\"` is C:\\ not C:\

Comment: Right click visual studio shortcut and click run as administrator

Comment: Thanks! I tried this too, but didn't work, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

> An unauthorized access exception occurs when I try to do it.

Just because you're an administrator doesn't mean you have access to everything. I haven't ever used it before, but the manual says [`SearchOption.AllDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does this:

> Includes the current directory and all its subdirectories in a search operation. This option includes reparse points such as mounted drives and symbolic links in the search.

So it's recursively searching C drive. Which means it's going to try to get into things like `System Volume Information` that a regular administrator won't have access to.

Short of setting one up yourself (and modifying ACLs on important system folders), I'm don't believe there's a security principal in Windows that has guaranteed access to everything on C drive. You should try recursing through the files and folders yourself and ignore folders you can't get into.